# Nested forms deletion not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

i'm using nested_form for adding and deleting nested_attributes.

```
class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :attachments_attributes
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

and the nested model

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :file
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

adding attachements works fine, but deleting doesent.

after clicking the delete link, the `text[attachments_attributes][0][_destroy]` input value changes from `false` to `1` so i think this is not the problem.

my update method:

```
  def update
    @text = Text.find(params[:id])
    if @text.update_attributes(params[:text])
      redirect_to @text, :notice  => "Successfully updated text."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

the output of params in my update method is

```
attachments_attributes:
  '0':
    description: asdf asdf as fs
    _destroy: '1'
    id: '2'
  '1':
    description: ''
    _destroy: '1'
    id: '3'
  '2':
    description: asdsadasd
    _destroy: '1'
    id: '4'
```

i cannot find the problem, so do you have an idea whats going wrong?

thank you!
please leave a comment if something is unclear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `:allow_destroy => true` to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments`

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, :allow_destroy => true
```

More information http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html